# Acces and create List elements with referention

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, preferences

I'm new with Jsp and Servlets. So my first question is how to use List (ArrayList) elements with referentions on all my .Jsp pages and Servlet pages and my second question is how to read this List element in .Jsp files and Servlets.

When I used java classes without Jsp and create in several classes a referention to other classes with an List element then can I acces this referention everywhere I want. But how can I do this in JSP? And how can you read this array in a .Jsp file?

In java classes will I set a refention between two or more classes like this:

Class Users example:

```
 Public class User() {
     Private List<Role> allRoles = ArrayList<Role>(); // contains data insight from the class Role

     // things to do
 }
```

Comment: Better do a search for servlet tutorials and such, as there are several choices one can make on some different techniques. To have a broad perspective. You can put objects as session attribute or request attribute, and query them in the JSP using EL, Expression Language. And so on.

Comment: Thanks, the Expression language is right wath I mean.